# Different model output in Mac and PC

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have been working on my PC to analyse my multilevel data. I am now working on a Mac and have run the same model. Some of the output is the same but some is quite different. I can't seem to work out why. Here is the model:

```
> loss.2 <- glmer.nb(Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c*Valence.c + (Valence.c|mood.c/Chain), data = FinalData_forpoisson, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", check.conv.grad = .makeCC("warning", 0.05)))
```

On the PC I got this output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(4.9852)  ( log )
Formula: Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c * Valence.c + (Valence.c | mood.c/Chain)
   Data: FinalData_forpoisson
Control: ..3

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1894.7   1945.3   -936.4   1872.7      725 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3882 -0.7225 -0.5190  0.4375  7.1873 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr
 Chain:mood.c (Intercept) 8.782e-15 9.371e-08     
              Valence.c   9.608e-15 9.802e-08 0.48
 mood.c       (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.000e+00     
              Valence.c   1.654e-14 1.286e-07  NaN
Number of obs: 736, groups:  Chain:mood.c, 92; mood.c, 2

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -0.19255    0.04794  -4.016 5.92e-05 ***
Posn.c           -0.61011    0.04122 -14.800  < 2e-16 ***
Valence.c        -0.27372    0.09589  -2.855  0.00431 ** 
Posn.c:Valence.c  0.38043    0.08245   4.614 3.95e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Posn.c Vlnc.c
Posn.c       0.491              
Valence.c    0.029 -0.090       
Psn.c:Vlnc. -0.090  0.062  0.491
```

On the Mac I got this output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(4.9852)  ( log )
Formula: Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c * Valence.c + (Valence.c | mood.c/Chain)
   Data: FinalData_forpoisson
Control: ..3

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1894.7   1945.3   -936.4   1872.7      725 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3882 -0.7225 -0.5190  0.4375  7.1873 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr
 Chain:mood.c (Intercept) 1.242e-13 3.524e-07     
              Valence.c   4.724e-13 6.873e-07 0.98
 mood.c       (Intercept) 7.998e-16 2.828e-08     
              Valence.c   3.217e-14 1.793e-07 1.00
Number of obs: 736, groups:  Chain:mood.c, 92; mood.c, 2

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)       2.947e-05  4.794e-02   0.001    1.000
Posn.c            7.441e-05  4.122e-02   0.002    0.999
Valence.c        -4.011e-05  9.589e-02   0.000    1.000
Posn.c:Valence.c -6.672e-05  8.245e-02  -0.001    0.999

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Posn.c Vlnc.c
Posn.c       0.491              
Valence.c    0.029 -0.090       
Psn.c:Vlnc. -0.090  0.062  0.491
```

Does anyone know why the output might be different across the two platforms and how I might be able to get them to align?

Comment: You should focus the question on the discrepancies that bother you. Note however that numerical differences may occur since these platforms may not be using the same underlying numerical libraries.

Comment: Is the data available for sharing?  Not sure there's much help that could be offered otherwise as I'm guessing that this issue is for this data rather than datasets in general.  I do see that both sets of random effects estimates are very near zero.  Possibly there's a data scaling issue.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825599/different-model-output-in-mac-and-pc